# biopython qblast function no data returned

Tags: biopython

I'm trying to blast an 8-mer (string of length 8) against the NCBI database. However, whenever I use qblast, it comes up empty with respect to matches. This is my code:

```
from Bio.Blast.NCBIWWW import qblast  
import Bio.Blast.NCBIXML as parser

a = qblast('blastp','nr','GGMPSGCS')  
b = parser.read(a)  
print b.alignments`
```

Whenever I do this, it just prints the empty list []. Why is this happening? Can anyone shine a light on it?

I can get a match using the NCBI online BLAST tool, and I can even get a match if I use a longer kmer like "SSRVQDGMGLYTARRVR". It just happens that all the 8-mers I search come up empty.

Answer (score 1):

From the FAQ at http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html

> Why doesn’t Bio.Blast.NCBIWWW.qblast() give the same results as the NCBI BLAST website?
>   You need to specify the same options – the NCBI often adjust the default settings on the >website, and they do not match the QBLAST defaults anymore. Check things like the gap >penalties and expectation threshold.

Check that qblast is using the same defaults, if not sure, make them explicit. I wouldn't be surprised if it's doing some sort of "read to short" filtering step.

Answer (score 1):

As in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698333/1688590), you have to fine-tuning the qblast to override the defaults. The WWW frontend of NCBI-BLAST automatically adjusts your parameters to match the short (8 bp) sequences, but if you do it through Biopython API you have to do it manually.