# blast against genomes in biopython

Tags: biopython, blast, genome

```py
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast(
    "blastn",
    "nr",
    "CACTTATTTAGTTAGCTTGCAACCCTGGATTTTTGTTTACTGGAGAGGCC",
    entrez_query='"Beutenbergia cavernae DSM 12333" [Organism]')

blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)

for blast_record in blast_records:
    for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            print(hsp.query[0:75] + '...')
            print(hsp.match[0:75] + '...')
            print(hsp.sbjct[0:75] + '...')
```

this does not give me an output, although the sequence is actually a sequence of the genome,
so i must get a result.
where is the error?
the query is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query isn't returning any results. The default parameters for blast are the cause. These parameters work better *in this particular case* of small length queries:

```
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast(
    "blastn",
    "nr",
    "CACTTATTTAGTTAGCTTGCAACCCTGGATTTTTGTTTACTGGAGAGGCC",
    megablast=False,
    expect=1000,
    word_size=7,
    nucl_reward=1,
    nucl_penalty=-3,
    gapcosts="5 2",
    entrez_query='Beutenbergia cavernae DSM 12333 [Organism]')
```

Particularly the `expect` parameter plays a major role here.